# emacs - after-change-functions are not executed after buffer modification

Tags: emacs, elisp, hook

I have added a function to `after-change-functions` list using this code

```
(defun test-func () 
    (message "foo")) 

(add-hook 'after-change-functions 'test-func nil t)
```

Now whenever i change buffer manually, `test-func` is getting called. But when i programatically modify the buffer using `insert`, the contents of buffer are getting updated, but `test-func` is not getting called.

Any pointers on how to activate `test-func` everytime buffer is updated?

**Update:**

I am trying to convert [markdown to html](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/impatient-markup/blob/master/impatient-markup.el#L48) and serve that on browser, so that whenever user types some markdown, html will be updated automatically.

Here is original implementation of `test-func`

```
(defun impatient-markup-update (&rest args)
  "Update html buffer if markup buffer updates."
  (save-buffer impatient-markup-buffer)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer impatient-markup-html-buffer)
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert (shell-command-to-string 
             (format "%s %s" impatient-markup-pandoc impatient-markup-buffer)))))
```

Comment: How do you know it is not getting called? What happens if you use use `sleep-for` after `message` or you call `insert` in `test-func` to insert `@@@@@@@@@@@@`?

Comment: @Drew because i dont see the side effect. i dont want to use `sleep-for` as i need side effect immediately. i am actually calling `insert` in `test-func` but its not working.

Comment: Maybe, https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode helps?

Comment: OK, I posted the comments as an answer, and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sleep-for` after the call to `message`, as a test, to see whether you see the message then.

`after-change-functions` does not necessarily run your hook in the buffer you expect. And as the doc says:

> *Buffer changes made while executing the `after-change-functions` don't call any before-change or after-change functions. That's because `inhibit-modification-hooks` is temporarily set non-nil.

Check what else is on that hook, etc. IOW, do a little debugging.

Comment: `(let ((inhibit-modification-hooks nil))
   (my-custom-function))` solved the problem